# accessing port 9000 in php-fpm

Tags: php

I let php-fpm listen on 0.0.0.0:9000, and also allowed client has external IPs,

if I do:

http://x.x.x.x/info.php
it works,

if I do
http://x.x.x.x:9000/info.php

it won't display the page

any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: With what web server?  Apache/Nginx?  Did you restart the webserver after applying the config changes?

Comment: nginx, I did not restart. my purpose is to have something like this: proxy_pass   http://198.199.70.140:9000/myapp/;  that's an external IP instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: you always need to restart the webserver for config changes to take effect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-fpm is not a web server and therefore do not accept HTTP requests.

You have to access it through a web server like nginx should you want to make a HTTP request.